# Put a input required in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a form in cakephp that have some inputs that are just for confirmation, these fields are not fields that belong to a table database. Like this:

A password confirmation field, this field is not on the database, is just to check some logic things. How can I make this field required (notEmpty rule)? Is it right to create this "validation" on the model even if this field does not belong to a the table of this model??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can validate fields that are not in the database - just like you normally would.  It just won't save anything to the database (of course).

Links to validation information (to save someone who finds this answer a Google search):

[CakePHP 2.x Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation)

[CakePHP 1.3 Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1143/Data-Validation)

Comment: Thanks, I had this doubt if the validation of something that is not in database is the same like validating some field that is. :)